# Export react component to an Existing Projects/Another web applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

I need advice on what approach to use for Export react component to an Existing Projects.

I have react component/app, for instance:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-div">
        <MyComponent />
        <MyComponent2 />
        <MyComponent3 />
        <CusTable headers={sampleHeader} data={sampleData} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and now I would need to get this component into other projects - Php, .Net Core + FE.

I already try run npm run build and insert all file paths "chunk" into HTML page (.aspx, .php). Thats work but i think its not ideal... in the future, I would also need to solve some input settings and output result...

I have founds articles:

[Exporting a Web Component from a React Codebase using Webpack: A step-by-step guide](https://jhinter.medium.com/exporting-a-web-component-from-a-react-codebase-using-webpack-a-step-by-step-guide-e6807a8baffd)

[@lit-labs/react package provides utilities to create React wrapper components for web components](https://lit.dev/docs/frameworks/react/)

[How To Add React To Existing Project Or Website?](https://blog.filestack.com/api/add-react-existing-project-website/)

I would welcome an answer if it is possible, if so, what approach to choose, and finally refer to some libraries, frameworks or solutions...
Thanks a lot